# converting a string list with sub list from a file to a list

Tags: python-3.x

Ok here's my issue. i have these data in a text file and i am trying to get the string list back to a `list` so i can edit with the contents of the list but i cant seem to figure out what is the method i need.

I have tried with `.strip('[]\n').split(',')`. what i am trying to do is retrieve the string list as a `list` and edit an element's value then store it back the the file. Thank you in advanced for your time and effort i really appreciate it.

Hope i am clear, thank you for your attention.

```
with open("acc.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        match = False

        while match != True:
            line = line.strip("][\n").split(",")
            print(type(line))
            print(line)
            match = True
```

the content of the file:[contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJSeq.png)

the output of .strip('[]\n').split(','):[output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtfAg.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please avoid pasting images if you can. Share some problematic lines from the input file which people can copy and paste,  and also what is the expected output.

Comment: oh my apologies. will make sure not to do that next time. thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the nested list you can do something like this:

```
extracted_list = []
for item in input_list:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        extracted_list = item
print(extracted_list)
```

This will output:

```
['name', 'mail', '21', '123456']
```

If you need to extract all the elements into a single list you can do:

```
extracted_list = []
for item in input_list:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for element in item:
            extracted_list.append(element)
    else:
        extracted_list.append(item)
print(extracted_list)
```

This will output:

```
['999S10000019625', 'name', 'mail', '21', '123456', 0]
```